# Do a JSON With JS from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i got this

`var monthNames = ['jan', 'fev', 'mar', 'abr', 'mai', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'set', 'out', 'nov', 'dez'];`

i do this to get the actual month to format:

```
var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("pt-BR", { month: "short" }),
month1 = formatter.format(new Date()) ; 
var posicao = monthNames.indexOf(month1); 
var mesesSelecionados = monthNames.slice(posicao, 12);  
var mesesSelecionadosJson = {};
var arrayteste=[];
    for ( i =0 ; i< mesesSelecionados.length; i++ ){
        var teste = mesesSelecionados[i].toString();
        mesesSelecionadosJson   =  JSON.stringify({ Mes : mesesSelecionados[i]}, null  );

                arrayteste.push(mesesSelecionadosJson);

                console.log(arrayteste);
                console.log(mesesSelecionadosJson );
                };
```

so im trying get this: 
`[{Mes:"abr"}, {Mes:"mai"}...]` (with all values in array)

anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can map your array to objects:

```js
var monthNames = ['jan', 'fev', 'mar', 'abr', 'mai', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'set', 'out', 'nov', 'dez'];
var objectYouWant = monthNames.map(function(month) { return {Mes: month}; });
console.log(objectYouWant);
// To convert to json
var jsonYouThinkYouWant = JSON.stringify(objectYouWant);
console.log(jsonYouThinkYouWant );

// Object you think you want.
var objectYouThinkIsDifferent = [{Mes:'jan'}, {Mes:'fev'}, {Mes:'mar'}, {Mes:'abr'}, {Mes:'mai'}, {Mes:'jun'}, {Mes:'jul'}, {Mes:'ago'}, {Mes:'set'}, {Mes:'out'}, {Mes:'nov'}, {Mes:'dez'}];
// Notice that the object is the same as the object my solution provides in the log.
console.log(objectYouThinkIsDifferent);
```

Comment: no Ken, u gave me this: [{"Mes":"jan"},{"Mes":"fev"},{"Mes":"mar"},{"Mes":"abr"},{"Mes":"mai"},{"Mes":"jun"},{"Mes":"jul"},{"Mes":"ago"},{"Mes":"set"},{"Mes":"out"},{"Mes":"nov"},{"Mes":"dez"}]

Comment: What i need is: [{Mes:"jan"},{Mes:"fev"},{Mes:"mar"},{Mes:"abr"},{Mes:"mai"},{Mes:"jun"},{Mes:"jul"},{Mes:"ago"},{Mes:"set"},{Mes:"out"},{Mes:"nov"},{Mes:"dez"}]

Comment: @DiogoGuilhen The two objects you just commented are the same. Both arrays would behave the same if you were to write `array[0].mes`.

Comment: @DiogoGuilhen Updated my example to demonstrate that the two objects you have commented are in effect, the same.

Answer (score 0):

What i do is this:
and got the filter what i want!

```
var d = new Date();
var ds = d.toLocaleString().substring(6,10);
var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("pt-BR", { month: "short" }),
        month1 = formatter.format(new Date()) ;
var monthNames = ['jan', 'fev', 'mar', 'abr', 'mai', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'set', 'out', 'nov', 'dez'];
var posicao = monthNames.indexOf(month1);
var mesesSelecionados = monthNames.slice(posicao, 12);

app1.field('[Ano]').selectMatch(ds, true);
app1.field('[Tempo]').selectMatch("Mes", true);
app1.field('[Compara]').selectMatch("Escala", true);
app1.field('[messtr]').selectValues( mesesSelecionados, true );
```